# Logging in to a website with C#

Tags: c#, browser, web-crawler

I'm sorry if this subject has already been answered, but I couldn't find what I needed (yet).

I'm working on a program that downloads files from university websites that use the same infrastructure. It's an open source project which I'm trying to support in my free time
(hosted in goodle code: http://code.google.com/p/highlearner/)

Until now we used GET and POST requests to login into the right page and download stuff. But the universities keep changing their websites and every little change requires teaking in Highlearner, which requires a new version, auto-updating all users, etc. Also, every university has its own login page, requiring me to tailor a login sequences..

So I'm looking for a more robust solution. Instead of manually redirecting and setting the HTTP parameters. Is there some kind of mini browser that supports with HTML + Javascript? No GUI is needed, I just need the engine.
This way, I will simply need to fill out the form parameters and let the browser do the work.

Thanks,
Nitay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to automate the process with [WatiN](http://watin.org) library . It allows you to click buttons, submit forms, etc.

```
using (var ie = new IE(loginUrl)) 
{
    if (ie.TextField("username").Exists 
       && ie.TextField("password").Exists)
    {
        ie.TextField("username").Value = "username";
        ie.TextField("password").Value = "password";
        ie.Button(Find.ByName("submit")).Click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well that eases things up. I'll check that out. Thanks!